# How to specify the primary keys for join table

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I have a class that has a `List` that I wish to relate to through a join table to allow 1-M and M-1 relations in the same time. In other words, I'd like to reuse the elements in the list.

In case that doesn't make sense or is inapplicable in a way please advice as I'm still trying to design that part of the model.

So the list is mapped this way:

```
@Persistent(table = "ixl_csv_metric_rel", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
@Join(column = "ixl_csv_fk")
@Order(column = "order")
@Element(dependent = "true", column = "ixl_metric_fk")
private List<IxlMetric> metrics;
```

The thing is that the join table is created with a compound primary key composed of the `ixl_csv_fk` and `order` columns which isn't what I need. The primary key would better be composed of the `ixl_metric_fk` column instead of the `order` column which make a lot more sense to me.

I can disable generating the primary key and set it manually later on but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it ?

```
@Join(column = "ixl_csv_fk", extensions = { @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "primary-key", value = "false") })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other way. Disable it and manually override it yourself. JDO provides the only sensible way of doing it to match the class definitions and a List field.

Comment: Thank you. Could that be enhanced in the future ?